# Add data to iBeacon Advertising Packet

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

How can I add data (such as broadcasting its name) via iBeacon Advertising Packet?

My current scenario: I have 3 transmitters and 1 receiver. But I can't differentiate among them, unless I turn on or off the transmitter one by one.

How can I broadcast information to receiver? and how can I retrieve such data?

The receiver code is as follow ( in App Delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ):

```
NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];
NSString *regionIdentifier = @"us.iBeaconModules";
CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID identifier:regionIdentifier];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate them by setting **major** and **minor** parameters of beacon.

You are using UUID `@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"` so I can assume that you have RedBear Beacon.

If so, you can download [app](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/redbear-beacontool/id828819434?mt=8) and configure your beacon (major, minor, uuid etc.).

**Edit**:
As @Daij-Djan wrote - you can use CoreBluetooth and receive name, battery level and other parameters by UUIDs of services and characteristic. 
For example, u can read description of services and characteristic of RedBear beacons [here](http://www.redbear.net/support.html).

Comment: Great idea. Actually I'm using AirLocate & iBeaconUS demo. I can assign different version numbers to imply different ID of the beacons. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that with iBeacons api -- you can specify custom data if you 'drop down' to the BLE layer

Comment: Not even device's name? Oops. So I have to use CoreBluetooth API instead?

Comment: yes, thats what you'll have to do .. OR you use an online backend to distribute data